# How to put data into control element in TabControl (MFC)?

Tags: c++, mfc

There is TabControl on a Dialog based application in MFC.

Each tab page is created as a dialog.

Here is the code for one of these pages:

```
class CTabPage1 : public CDialogEx
{

    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTabPage1)

public:

    CTabPage1(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CTabPage1();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_TABPAGE1 };

protected:

    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
    CComboBox *m_pStyles;

public:

    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
};
```

and here is the realization:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestProject.h"
#include "TestProjectDlg.h"
#include "TabPage1.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// CTabPage1 dialog


IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CTabPage1, CDialogEx)
CTabPage1::CTabPage1(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CTabPage1::IDD, pParent)
{    
    m_pStyles = new CComboBox;
}



CTabPage1::~CTabPage1()
{
}

void CTabPage1::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{

    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO1, *m_pStyles);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTabPage1, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// CTabPage1 message handlers
int CTabPage1::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    m_pStyles->AddString("aaa");
    UpdateData(0);
    return 0;
}
```

compiling is ok, but when trying to run this code there is a 
Debug Assertion Failed!

as far, as i can understand, the assertion comes from dlgcore.cpp, function:

```
    hWnd = ::CreateDialogIndirect(hInst, lpDialogTemplate,
        pParentWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), AfxDlgProc);
```

Please, tell, where is the mistake?
How to put data into m_pStyle ComboBox?
Maby it should be done in another method...

ADDITION.
Here is the code of the main Dialog:
Header file:

```
#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"
#include "TabPage1.h"


// CTestProjectDlg dialog
class CTestProjectDlg : public CDialogEx
{
// Construction
public:
    CTestProjectDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_TESTPROJECT_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;  
    CTabCtrl m_Tabs;                 
    CTabPage1 *m_pStyles;       

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    afx_msg BOOL DestroyWindow();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
public:
    afx_msg void OnSelchangeTab1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
    afx_msg void OnSelchangingTab1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
};
```

and the source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestProject.h"
#include "TestProjectDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTestProjectDlg dialog




CTestProjectDlg::CTestProjectDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CTestProjectDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);

    m_pTabPage1 = new CTabPage1;         
}

void CTestProjectDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TAB1, m_Tabs);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestProjectDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB1, &CTestProjectDlg::OnSelchangeTab1)
    ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGING, IDC_TAB1, &CTestProjectDlg::OnSelchangingTab1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTestProjectDlg message handlers

BOOL CTestProjectDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here


    TC_ITEM tci;                
    tci.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    tci.iImage = -1;

    tci.pszText = "Page1";          
    m_Tabs.InsertItem(0, &tci);     
    tci.pszText = "Page2";        
    m_Tabs.InsertItem(1, &tci);    


    // first TabPage
    tci.mask = TCIF_PARAM;
    tci.lParam = (LPARAM)m_pTabPage1;
    m_Tabs.SetItem(0, &tci);

    m_pTabPage1->Create(CTabPage1::IDD, &m_Tabs);
    m_pTabPage1->SetWindowPos(NULL, 30, 30, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    m_pTabPage1->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);   

    // Second TabPage
    tci.mask = TCIF_PARAM;
    tci.lParam = (LPARAM)m_pTabPage2;
    m_Tabs.SetItem(1, &tci);

    m_pTabPage2->Create(CTabPage2::IDD, &m_Tabs);
    m_pTabPage2->SetWindowPos(NULL, 30, 30, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    m_pTabPage2->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CTestProjectDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CTestProjectDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CTestProjectDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


void CTestProjectDlg::OnSelchangeTab1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    int iTab = m_Tabs.GetCurSel();
    TC_ITEM tci;
    tci.mask = TCIF_PARAM;
    m_Tabs.GetItem(iTab, &tci);
    CWnd* pWnd = (CWnd *)tci.lParam;
    pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); 

    *pResult = 0;
}

void CTestProjectDlg::OnSelchangingTab1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    int iTab = m_Tabs.GetCurSel();
    TC_ITEM tci;
    tci.mask = TCIF_PARAM;
    m_Tabs.GetItem(iTab, &tci);
    CWnd* pWnd = (CWnd *)tci.lParam;
    pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE); 

    *pResult = 0;
}

BOOL CTestProjectDlg::DestroyWindow() 
{
    delete m_pTabPage1;

    return CDialog::DestroyWindow();
}
```

When i put ComboBox on a main Dialog window and try to add data it works. But the dialog on a tab page is a child dialog. Maby in this case it doesn't call some initialization function for its controls? Because in debug mode i can see the object m_pStyles, but not its properties?

Maybe there is some tutorial on how to work with TabControl?

Comment: Show the code that creates the dialog. That appears to be where the problem originates. Also, you seem to have a CComboBox but have not created the CComboBox window. Is the combo on the dialog template or are you attempting to create it dynamically.

Comment: Look into the call stack. Who calls the code that causes the assertion?

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP. i create ComboBox dynamically in CTabPage1 constructor. But even if define the instant of CComboBox as CComboBox m_style instead of pointer it doesn't work :(

Comment: @xMRi. sorry, i don't know how to do that correctly. There is additional code in question. Maby now you can help?

Comment: The code doesn't help me. When the ASSERT comes, press Retry. Than look into the Debug Windows for the call stack. Check what of your code is called least.

Comment: @xMRi. The function is > mfc100d.dll!CWnd::CreateDlgIndirect(const DLGTEMPLATE * lpDialogTemplate, CWnd * pParentWnd, HINSTANCE__ * hInst)  Line 366 + 0x2a bytes C++
Near this function there is a green arrow.

Comment: No! There must be something that you call! I mean not the code in the MFC. What is your code?

Comment: @xMRi.   TestProject.exe!CTestProjectApp::InitInstance()  Line 72 + 0xb bytes C++

Comment: Maybe the sheme is wrong? Should child window process information by itself or more correctly to process data and fill the controls from the main dialog?

Comment: We are trying to figure out which dialog is causing the problem. What is the code at InitInstance Line 72 and nearby? Double click on the line in the stack window and it will display the line in the code that leads to the problem. And a guess: In InitInstance you need to call InitCommonControlsEx before creating the main dialog.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP. InitInstance calls INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();, DoModal calls CreateDlgIndirect(lpDialogTemplate, CWnd::FromHandle(hWndParent), hInst). In CreateDlgIndirect the assertion comes from hWnd = ::CreateDialogIndirect(hInst, lpDialogTemplate, pParentWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), AfxDlgProc);. InitCommotControls is called:InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP. Maybe InitCommonControlsEx() should be called for the child dialog separately? Or any other initialization? And should m_Tabs (an instance of CTabControl) be created as a child of main dialog?

Comment: InitCommonControlsEx is needed only once, before creating any controls. At this point I would comment out everything having to do with the ComboBox (you have several problems with it) just to get the  main dialog, and then the tab dialog, alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: just to use another handler to initialize the controls, not `OnCreate`, but `OnShow` for example. (Object isn't created, but i want to do something with it ).